# Missing Rows Property in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
public bool ValidateUser(string uName)
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  if (connection == null)
  {
    connection = connectToDB();
  }
  cmd.Connection = connection;
  cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Users where UserName='" + uName + "'";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
  if (dr.Rows.Count > 0) 
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
```

I wrote the code in my data access layer but it was giving error on rows to count the columns.

Error:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: Error 4 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3):

Use `HasRows` instead because `SqlDataReader` doesn't have a property call `Rows`.

```
if (dr.HasRows) 
{
    return true;
}
```

However, if you want the count instead you may load it into a datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
int num = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

SqlDataReader does not have a Rows Property.

Perhaps consider the HasRows property of SqlDataReader
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no Rows property in an SqlDataReader.
But your code has many problems.
I would change your code in this way:

```
    public bool ValidateUser(string uName)
    {
        using(SqlConnection cn = connectToDB())
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Users where UserName=@name", cn))
        {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", uName);
           return (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
        }
    }
```

- The connection object is no more global and it is destroyed in
  closing of the using statement.
- No need to use a DataReader just to find out if the user exists or
  not
- Using a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection on the input data

Avoid a global connection object. There is the [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) infrastructure that removes any performance problem and you are safe from excessive resource usage.
The SqlDataReader is a good choice when you need to retrieve sequentially a lot of records, but to get just the information if the user exists or not the best approach is through the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method and an appropriate sql.
The parameterized query is a must for every serious database work. It will pass the work to format your input to the framework and you don't risk an [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)